# How to Export data fields from .dbf to .sqlite table using php script

Tags: php, sqlite, foxpro

How to export all data fields in database foxpro table (.dbf) to sqlite  table (.sqlite) using php script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

php has support for both, see the documentation for more details:

- [dBase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dbase.php)
- [sqlite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php)

I don't know if you actually have more specific issues, so this is as detailed as my answer can be. Please provide more details for a more specific answer.

Comment: i need to convert all fields in the dbf format to sqlite database format. please help me to solve the problem above mentioned..